# If $n^2+3n$ is a multiple of $3$, then $n$ is a multiple of $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to use contraposition to answer this proof.. I am new to this so am still trying to figure it all out..

I know the contrapositive statement is

'If $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ then $n^2 + 3n$ is not a multiple of $3$'

My issue is I am not quite sure where to start with proving it.

Comment: Well, if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ then either $n=3m+1$ or $n=3m-1$ for some $m$.

Comment: For me it’s easier to prove directly:  $3|n^2+3n\implies 3|n^2\implies3|n$

Comment: lulu thanks for that..

Comment: Just factorise it to get $n(n+3)$ then $3|n\implies3|n(n+3)$ but otherwise we have $n\equiv n+3\mod{3}$ so neither of the factors can be divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to use the contrapositive...**

If $n$ is not a multiple of 3 then either $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $n \equiv -1 \pmod 3$.

In the first case, $n^2 \equiv 1^2 \pmod 3$ and so $n^2 + 3n \equiv 1 + 0 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and so is not a multiple of 3.

In the second case, $n^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \pmod 3$ and so once again, with remainder 1, $n^2 + 3n$ is not a multiple of 3.

**Alternatively, a direct proof is:**

$n^2 + 3n$ is divisible 3 by only if both $n^2$ and $3n$ are divisible by 3. Well, clearly $3n$ is divisible by 3, and so $n^2 + 3n$ will only be divisible by 3 if $n^2$ is divisible by 3. Since 3 is prime, $n^2$ is divisible by 3 only if $n$ is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 4):

$3|n^2+3n\Longrightarrow 3|n^2$ since $3|3n$. And since 3 is prime, thus $3|n^2\Longrightarrow 3|n$

Answer (score 0):

Let's $n=3q+r$ then $n^2+3n\bmod 3\equiv n^2 \equiv (3q+r)^2 \equiv r^2\pmod 3$

Now examine the values of $r^2$ for $r=0,1,2$ and conclude.